# Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, codeblocks

I'm getting this error (*s = *end; line) during debugging, while trying to reverse string using pointers.
I'm using Windows 10 OS, codeblocks IDE and GDB debugger.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

void myreverse(char* s);

int main()
{
    char* s1 = "1234";
    myreverse(s1);
    printf("%s", s1);
    return 0;
}

void myreverse(char* s) {
    char tmp;
    char* end = s + strlen(s) - 1;

    for(; s < end; s++, end--) {
        tmp = *s;
        *s = *end;
        *end = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: `char* s1 = "1234";` should be `const char* s1 = "1234";` or `char s1[] = "1234";` if you mean to change it.

Comment: ^^^^ which will break your build, rather than invoke *undefined behavior* like you're doing now. Don't be surprised, that's what you want in this case, as it calls out the real problem. Then, change `const char *s1 = "1234";` to `char s1[] = "1234";`, and give it another rip.

Comment: It also looks like `*end = *s;` should be `*end = tmp;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `s1` to `char s1[] = "1234";` since you are making changes to the string.

Then in your `myreverse()` function, you never use the `tmp` variable, which makes your swap block failing.

Fixed:

```
#include <cstdio>   // use the C++ versions of the header files
#include <cstring>

void myreverse(char* s) {
    char tmp;
    char* end = s + std::strlen(s) - 1;

    for(; s < end; s++, end--) {
        // swap
        tmp = *s;
        *s = *end;
        *end = tmp;   // use tmp
    }
}

int main() {
    char s1[] = "1234";
    myreverse(s1);
    printf("%s", s1);
}
```

Note that the 3 lines in the swap block can be replaced with [`std::swap(*s, *end);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) and also that `myreverse()` can be completely replaced with [`std::reverse(std::begin(s1), std::end(s1));`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).